# Angular: input type="date" with initial value

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-date-format

I have two inputs type="date" to filter the data by period.
I would like to bring them with value already informed when loading the page.

First input with value Date() -7.

Second input with Date().

This is my angular code:

```
<input type="date" class="form-control form-date" [(ngModel)]="dtInitial">       
<input type="date" class="form-control form-date" [(ngModel)]="dtFinal">´
```

Since now, thank you who can help me.

Comment: Well, nothing happens when I click Run code snippet, because Angular is not imported, and there is no `dtInitial` or `dtFinal` properties for `ngModel` to work off of. Please show more of your code. You need not use the Stack Snippet functionality if the code is not runnable.

Comment: @HereticMonkey, I changed Stack Snippet to code. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score -1):

Your input should take in a string. Try to convert the date to a string in the component.

```
@Component({
  selector: "example",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  providers: [DatePipe]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  dtInitial: string = "";
  dtFinal: string = "";

  constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    let today: Date = new Date();
    let sevenDaysAgo = new Date();
    sevenDaysAgo.setDate(today.getDate()-7)
    this.dtInitial = this.datePipe.transform(today, "yyyy-MM-dd");
    this.dtFinal = this.datePipe.transform(sevenDaysAgo, "yyyy-MM-dd");
 }
}
```

Alternatively, you could also use the datePipe directly in the template. You can format your date in other ways. Here you see some diffferent formats you can use: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Date_and_time_formats#format_of_a_valid_date_string.

If you want to make the inputs update when one of them is changed you could add this to the component.

```
 updateDateInitial() {
   let newDate = new Date(this.dtInitial);
   newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate()-7)
   this.dtFinal = this.datePipe.transform(newDate, "yyyy-MM-dd");
 }

 updateDateFinal() {
    let newDate = new Date(this.dtInitial);
    newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate()+7)
    this.dtInitial = this.datePipe.transform(newDate, "yyyy-MM-dd");
 }
```

and this for the inputs.

```
<input (change)="updateDateInitial()" type="date" class="form-control form-date" [(ngModel)]="dtInitial">       
<input (change)="updateDateFinal()" type="date" class="form-control form-date" [(ngModel)]="dtFinal">
```

That how you could do it - but in general, you should consider if two-binding is the way to go :)

Comment: It has to be a string in a specific format to work with `input type="date"`...